# php Password textbox!

Tags: php, text, textbox, passwords

[image]

```
<input type="password" value="<?php echo md5($row['password']);?>">
<input type="password" value="<?php echo $row['password'];?>">
```

im trying to retrive the password from the database.
In input box, i want it show, let say password : 12345, instead of MD5 version of 12345.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve, and what the problem is?

Comment: still showing "long character" ?

Comment: Please be more specific. What happens on the second case?

Comment: I don't understand, what is the desired behavior?

Comment: Then what's wrong with the second line?

Comment: You really shouldn't be retrieving and displaying plaintext passwords in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MD5 is not reversible, and you shouldn't autofill a password field for security reasons.

It's showing longer because MD5ed strings are always 32 characters.

**edit:** You also shouldn't use a reversible password storage method. Please see [Jeff Atwood's "You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html) post for details.

Comment: All answers are telling the same thing...DON'T echo passwords!!

Answer (score 4):

It's outputting the MD5 hash because you're telling it to do just that:

```
echo md5($row['password']);
```

On a more general note, however, please ***do not output passwords to the page***.  Never, ever do this.  Don't even output the MD5 hash.  Don't output anything about the password.  You are essentially giving away passwords for anybody to see.

Also, [don't store passwords in plain text either](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you md5() the password in the value attribute of the input field, it's going to be the 32-character string. If you don't want it to be the md5()'ed string in the value then don't md5() it.

Can you expand your code to show what's actually happening and what you're looking to achieve?

Comment: so there is no way to convert it back to original! thanks for the advice :)

Comment: No, MD5 is a one-way encryption method. To be able to decrypt it you must use a different encryption method such as mcrypt.

Comment: Passwords shouldn't be stored in a non one-way method, regardless.

Answer (score -1):

It isnt possable, md5 is only one-way encryption, you cant decrypt it unless you bruteforce.